# tgamma выводит неправильный результат?

Tags: c, математика

Аргументом функции tgammaf или просто tgamma является ,например, такое:
tgamma(6.7)
*Вольфрамальфа* считает, что такое вещественное число будет равно приблизительно *2769.83*
Но эта маленькая программа выводит совсем не тот результат.Она выводит *413.407373*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float  a = 6.7;
    printf("%f", tgamma(a));
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему так ?
Как же всё-таки правильно взять факториал от вещественного числа

Comment: может быть , это потому что Г(n-1)!   ?

Comment: Нет, это потому что `Г(n) = (n-1)!`

Answer (score 0):

WolframAlpha так же считает, что `tgamma(6.7)` равняется 413.408

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ,я же хотел взять факториал от вещественного числа 6.7.Вольфрам там единичку вычитает, как в формуле

Comment: @Elvin Хотели - вот вам и результат. Что в Си, что в Вольфраме результат совпадает. Что вам не нравится?

Comment: не нравится то, что приходится прибавлять единичку ,например, к 6.7 , а именно 7.7 , что результат (6.7)! был верным.Видимо, это всё из-за формулы  , где есть вычитание единицы

Comment: @Elvin Ну так сама-то гамма-функция работает правильно! Исправьте свой сишный код как `tgamma(a + 1)` и будет вам счастье.